# Find the range of the $\alpha$ for convergence of this series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$Q)$ Find the range of the $\alpha$ below series convergent

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (cos{1 \over n} -1 + {1 \over {2n^2}})^\alpha$

---

I'd like to introduce my method to you, because I can't find my mistake in my solution.

Clearly $sin^2({x \over 2}) = {{1 - cosx} \over 2}$, Hence $cos{1 \over n} -1 = -2sin^2({1 \over 2n})$.

Therefore just we left finding the $\alpha$ which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-2sin^2({1 \over 2n})+ {1 \over  {2n^2}})^\alpha$ is convergent.

Hence Considering $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ({1 \over n^2})^\alpha$, by limit comparison test, $\alpha > {1 \over 2}$

But the answer was $\alpha > {1 \over 4}$. What the point did I have a mistake? (I believe the answer is false.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why you compare it with $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ ? These terms are canceled out. The remaining part of Taylor series starts with $\frac{1}{n^{4}}$ like term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{[-2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2n})+\frac{1}{2n^2}]^\alpha}{[\frac{1}{n^2}]^\alpha}=0
$$
whenever $\alpha>0$.  However for the limit comparison test you need the limit to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor, use that
$$\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1+\frac{1}{2 n^2}=\frac{1}{24 n^4}-\frac{1}{720 n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^8}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2 n^2}-2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2 n}\right)=\frac{1}{24 n^4}-\frac{1}{720 n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^8}\right)$$